# Regular expression to match the first appearance of a character

Tags: regex

I'm far from a regex master, and I'm trying to match the first appearance of a semicolon for a Notepad++ search-and-replace and failing miserably at it.  The best I've come up with is the following:

```
[^.*];
```

I figured this would capture the beginning of the line, all characters (if any), and then get to the semicolon.  But this still ended up replacing all of the semicolons in the line.  It also consumed the character *before* the semicolon, and I have no clue at all why that happens, so if anyone could explain that phenomenon, that would be an added bonus (but of course not essential to the actual answer).

I've got nothin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the output before the semicolon in a group with parentheses, then the semicolon, then the remainder of the line. The following worked for me in Notepad++:

```
Find: ^([^;]*);(.*)$
Replace with: \1{whatever}\2
```

Comment: I'm amazed that such a semantically simple operation requires that much effort.  Haha.  Thank you so much.